# updating value in copied object is affecting all the other copied objects value in angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

---

In Component, I made http call to get all assignees from Backend.

Component :-

```
 const req = this.assigneeService.getAssignees();
    req.subscribe(
      data => {
        this.assignees = data['data'];
        // On response json will be like below
        [  
         {  
           name:"Name 3",
           id:1,
           status:"Not_Assigned"
         },
         {  
           name:"Archana",
           id:2,
           status:"Not_Assigned"
          }
        ]
       },
       err => {       
     }
 );
```

On click of button,the below function will call and create say objectM.
Now assume I have created 2 more same object say objectM1 and objectM2 with same method.

```
    public addObj1(): void {
        let asignees1 = this.assignees.slice(0);
        let objectM = new Module();
        objectM.assignees = asignees1;
      }

//onchange funtion where object is selected Object, action as string and id of user
    changeAssigneeState(object, action, assigneeId ) {

    for (let a of object.assignees) {
     if (a.id == assigneeId) {
        a.status = action;
      }
     }
    }
```

On changing the assignee.status of id 1 in objectM. It affects objectM1 and objectM2 assignee.status of same id.

Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`let asignees1 = this.assignees.slice(0);` clones array **but** objects inside have references to the objects in original array, you need to get deep clone of array of objects, you can do it using this simple trick:

```
let asignees1 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.assignees));
```

Then you will have cloned array with no references to original array.

Answer (score 1):

deep clone of array objects will help you out.try this,

```
let asigneesData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.assignees));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do it using `Object.assign()`

```
newAssignes = [];

this.assignees.forEach((assignee, i) => {
    this.newAssignes[i] = Object.assign({}, assignee)
});
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yfzxbq)